# Pentaho Data Integration - Connection time out

Tags: mysql, input, connection, timeout, pentaho

I am developing a PDI transformation, which takes data from a MySql database, and output the data into an MSSQL table. But before output, I add a deletion step to delete records in dest. table with same key field values. But I do not know why that by this setting the transformation always fails casting exception of connection timeout of data source.

But, after I added a "Block" step between "table input" and "Delete", the issue got gone, and the transformation got successfully finished.

My configuration and exception message are as blow:

[Transformation setting and system exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIAEg.png)

[Data Input SQL, and Delete condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0S2Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error what I see from the screen-shot you attached and also recommendation in the 4th error line from top "consider raising value of 'net_write_timeout' on the server"

Default value will be 60, Kindly increase the value for the same.
Follow below document for more reference.

https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MySQL

Comment: Hi Helping Hand
Thank you for the reply. Do you mean change the parameter in MySql? I added a parameter "net_write_timeout" and set it 1800 in option of connection, but it did not work. The mysql is a remote one, and I have no control over it. But I am still curious, why a "Block" step can help resolve this.

Comment: you have to modify "net_write_timeout" value in my.ini file.
answer to your block question, all the steps executes in parallel in pentaho etl , so once you put block step it waits for your table input step to finish, however you can provide more details like data volume in your select statement and if possible attach your transformation to check further.